# Using ifelse changes output it is not supposed to change

Tags: r, if-statement

```
ID <- 1:10
YOB <- c("2000", "2001", "2001", "2002", "2002", "2004", "2005", "2007", "2008", "2008")
born_before <- c("FALSE", "FALSE", "TRUE", "NA", "FALSE", "NA", "TRUE", "TRUE", "FALSE", "NA") 
df <- data.frame(ID, YOB, born_before)
```

I am trying to use an ifelse statement to change year of birth (YOB) to blanks if an individual is born before either of its parents (if born_before is true). If born_before is NA, I would also like to change YOB to a blanks. However, with this piece of code

```
df$YOB <- with(df, ifelse(born_before == TRUE, YOB == "", YOB))
```

my YOB gets changed completely to different numbers. The resulting dataframe looks like this

| ID | YOB | born_before |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | FALSE |
| 2 | 2 | FALSE |
| 3 | 0 | TRUE |
| 4 | 3 | NA |
| 5 | 3 | FALSE |
| 6 | 4 | NA |
| 7 | 0 | TRUE |
| 8 | 0 | TRUE |
| 9 | 7 | FALSE |
| 10 | 7 | NA |

when it should like this one

| ID | YOB | born_before |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2000 | FALSE |
| 2 | 2001 | FALSE |
| 3 |  | TRUE |
| 4 |  | NA |
| 5 | 2002 | FALSE |
| 6 |  | NA |
| 7 |  | TRUE |
| 8 |  | TRUE |
| 9 | 2008 | FALSE |
| 10 |  | NA |

Any ideas what is going wrong? I am a novice R user (have dabbled a bit) and would like to learn. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for answering my question! With your help I sort of stumbled upon answer. I used the following code

```
ID <- 1:10
YOB <- c("2000", "2001", "2001", "2002", "2002", "2004", "2005", "2007", "2008", "2008")
born_before <- c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, NA, FALSE, NA, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, NA) 
df <- data.frame(ID, YOB, born_before)

df$YOB <- as.numeric(as.character(df$YOB))

df1 <- transform(df, YOB = replace(YOB, born_before != FALSE, ""))
df2 <- transform(df1, YOB = replace(YOB, is.na(born_before), ""))
```

So, I changed born_before to a logical vector instead of character. And had R first read YOB as a character, and then as a numeric variable. For some reason the replace with the `!= FALSE` did not cover the NAs, which is why I added the line of code below it. And now it works! Thank you guys for your knowledge and time

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```r
df$YOB <- ifelse(df$born_before, "", df$YOB)
```

The `ifelse()` function is already vectorized.  Note also that you don't need to compare `born_before` to `TRUE` explicitly, assuming this column already contains a boolean value.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the code below using `replace`

```
transform(
  df,
  YOB = replace(YOB, born_before != "FALSE", "")
)
```

or `ifelse`

```
transform(
  df,
  YOB = ifelse(born_before != "FALSE", "", YOB)
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I get an error when I try to run the first piece of your code:
```
Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, is.na(df$YOB), value = "") :
duplicate subsscripts for columns
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using `case_when` from the `dplyr` package to return a value in `YOB` based on the checks performed on the values in the `born_before` variable. In this case, it is checking whether `born_before` is `NA` or `TRUE`.

`case_when` is a function that allows you to vectorise multiple `if_else()` statements.

```r
df <- data.frame(
           ID = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L),
          YOB = c(2000, 2001, 2005, 2003, 2002, 2001, 2009, 2005, 2008, 2001),
  born_before = c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, NA, FALSE, NA, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, NA)
)

library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(
    YOB = case_when(
      is.na(born_before) | born_before ~ "",
      TRUE ~ as.character(YOB)
    )
  )

# OUTPUT: 

#>    ID  YOB born_before
#> 1   1 2000       FALSE
#> 2   2 2001       FALSE
#> 3   3             TRUE
#> 4   4               NA
#> 5   5 2002       FALSE
#> 6   6               NA
#> 7   7             TRUE
#> 8   8             TRUE
#> 9   9 2008       FALSE
#> 10 10               NA
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

**NOTE**

The data you provided has `YOB` and `born_before` as a character types. If this is an accurate representation of your dataset, you will want to run the following code prior to my code so that you have the correct types for each variable.

`type.convert(df)`

Comment: Thank you for explaining! I get a warning message however when I run the code you provided. 
```Problem with `mutate()` input `YOB`. 
' | ' not meaningful for factors. 
Input `YOB` is case_when(is.na(born_before) | born_before ~ "", TRUE ~as.character(YOB))`.
```
Is it going wrong because YOB is read as a factor?